# Can't Delete Cookies with AngularJs

Tags: cookies, angularjs

I cannot seem to delete cookies with Angularjs. What can be wrong.. Her is the code..

```
$scope.adminLogout = function(){
    $http({
        url: '/AdServerLongTail/adminapi/logout',
        method: "POST",
        dataType:"json",                                
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("success");
            delete $cookies["username"]; 
            delete $cookies["JSESSIONID"];                
            $rootScope.welcome=null;
            $location.path("/admin");                
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log("error");               
   });          
}
```

html

```
<li><a href="#" ng-click="adminLogout()">LOGOUT</a></li>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I dont get any, it just doesnt delete them

Comment: I got the same issue with pure javascript. I have to delete the session in django bankend, then I succeed to logout. The function is `django.contrib.auth.views.logout(request)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs - cookies will get update at the end of the current $eval cycle (which is part of the $digest cycle). This means you might not see the cookies deleted straight away.

On a slightly different not the Angularjs Cookies library is quite broken and should not be used for any production ready project (for example you can't set expire time etc.)